# Compile 64-bit binary with MinGW (Dev-C++)

Tags: c++, windows, g++, 64-bit, dev-c++

It is probably a stupid question but i was searching for the answer from about 3h.

**¿How to compile 64-bit binary with (Dev-C++) MinGW?**

I  have readed that MinGW support 64bits by default, but i am unable to active this option.

I have tryed "-m64" but it say: "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in"

I am working on Dev-C++ on Windows-7

I know how to do it on MSVC++, but I don't want MSVC++ (cause of ethical issues)

What i am trying to compile, just for testing purpose:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    // Test compiling mode
    if (sizeof(void*) == 8) cout << "Compiling 64-bits" << endl;
    else cout << "Compiling 32-bits" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of MinGW do you have? There seems to be a separate distro for 64 bit.

Comment: +1 for "I dont want MSVC++ (cause of ethical issues)"

Comment: @doctorlove MinGW GCC 4.7.2 32-bit

Comment: @AdrianMaire I've added some more details you can try out that may be easier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To build a 64-bit binary on windows you need the 64-bit version of the mingw compiler. Mingw-W64 is one possible distribution you can use. You can find a list of **[downloads here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php)**.

Additionally, you can also find Dev-C++ setup bundled with mingw 64-bit compiler under **[Orwell Dev-C++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/)**'s download section. Make sure you choose "*TDM-GCC x64 4.7.1*" either setup or portable.

Comment: thanks your! I have tryed to install the Mingw-W64 but get error (it seem to has not access to his repository, probably a temporal issue with their servers). The second option work fine.

Comment: @Adrian Maire MinGW w64 is a very good compiler, i use it all the time. mingwbuilds provides the best general builds and is used by many in the areospace and automotive industries. You can find their 64 bit builds [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/), there's pivots for seh and sjlj, as well as posix and win32 threading models.

Comment: Orwell DevCpp did it! ...or later version of TDM-GCC, of course.