# Qt .exe file error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, user-interface, qt-creator

I was making a sleeping detection program with GUI. I decided to choose Qt for the project. I was able to build the program but when I ran it, this message popped up which I had no idea what was wrong.

> Starting
>   C:\Users\Helianthus\Documents\QtProject\build-facelandmark-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\facelandmark.exe...
>
> Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
>
> C:/Users/Helianthus/Documents/QtProject/build-facelandmark-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/facelandmark.exe
>   exited with code -1
>
> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program
>   "C:/Users/Helianthus/Documents/QtProject/build-facelandmark-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/facelandmark.exe"
>   is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the
>   program.

Comment: Does the path exist? Does the "facelandmark.exe" file exist at that path?

Comment: Yes, I thought that it was either the file was not there or something else. Sadly the file was there and I don't know what was wrong. I use window 7 btw.

Comment: Are you using Qt Creator? If you just double click on the exe file from windows explorer does the same thing happen?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Qt Creator. When I clicked from windows explorer I got this message:
"C:\user\...\facelandmark.exe is not a valid Win32 application".

Comment: Are you running 32-bit version of windows? or 64 bit?

Comment: My computer is running Window7 64-bit.

Comment: Ok that might be the problem. I'm not very experienced with MinGW but looks like you're building using 32 bit right?

Comment: I think so. My OpenCV was built with MinGW32 and generated x86 library, also the same with dlib so I guest my program is 32 bit. If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: You'll need to recompile everything with a 64 bit compiler. There is a 64 bit version of MinGW (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988904/compile-64-bit-binary-with-mingw-dev-c)

Comment: Would it affect my Qt creator project, since it runs with mingw32?

Comment: Yes you'll need to reconfigure the project or change the tool chain it's using to compile.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and update the result.

Comment: @DeveloperPaul why should OP recompile eveything with a 64bit compiler? Win7 64bit is perfectly able to run 32bit applications (matter of fact many current applications are still 32bit)

Comment: @Alienpenguin looking back at comment chain now I think you're right. I don't know what my logic was at the time but the issue the OP experienced doesn't seem to be related to 64 versus 32 bit....

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Qt installation path(such as:'C:\Qt\Qt5.14.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin').
2. Right click on the 'QtCreate.exe' program.
3. Select 'Attributes' or 'Property' on the Menu.
4. Select 'Compatibility' tab on the popup window.
5. Click 'Change settings for all users' button.
6. Check 'Run as administrator'.
7. Click 'OK' to close all the popup window.
8. Restart QtCreator, you will find it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, I fixed it by doing the following:

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Buid & Run`, if you scroll down the bottom of the dialog, there is a dropdown field called `Build Before Deploying`, you just need to set that to `Build only the application to be run`, then run the application again.